# use public static from public String (non-static)

Tags: java, android

I need you help about using set variable static from variable non static on script
  `"GetIP_Public = this.conn_public;"`

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application {

    public String conn_public;
    public static GlobalClass GetIP_Public;


    public static GlobalClass GetIP_Public(){
      GetIP_Public = this.conn_public;
     return GetIP_Public;
    }

    private static class GetIP_Public {

    }

    public String getConn_public() {
        return conn_public;
    }

    public void setConn_public(String conn_public) {
        this.conn_public = conn_public;

    }
```

Comment: You understand the meaning of the `static` keyword?

Comment: do you understand how meaningless something like 'public static class GetIP_Public probably is?

Comment: You can use static things from a non-static context.  It's the other way around that's a problem.  In your code above, you've tried to use `this` inside a `static` method; but that makes no sense - `static` methods are ones that run without any `this` object.

Comment: I need give value static variable  form of data  non static variables

Comment: Its not possible. But i would like to know what compelled you to want such a behavior

Comment: please change my code... i'm first time work for android studio

Comment: I think you need to try again to explain what you're trying to do.  You _can't_ use non-static fields unless you've got an object that belongs to the class with those fields; and the whole point of a static method is that it's a place where you _don't_ need such an object.  So what you've asked for is not possible.  Can you please try to explain what problem you're trying to solve, without using the word "static"?

Comment: thank a lot for response.

Comment: 1. I have a spinner containing the  IP PUBLIC.
2. The selected IP will be saved at
public void setConn_public (String conn_public) {
         this.conn_public = conn_public;
     }
3. In other activities I need to take IP PUBLIC values that have been stored on conn_public

Comment: Sure.  I don't think you need anything to be static, in order to implement something like that.  Whatever object you use to store the IP just has to be passed around the various places that need it.

Comment: #Problem Solved. I use a non-static public variable on MainActivity, then on another activity I call that variable by the MainActivity. NameVariable.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase, i.e. they start with lowercase and do not contain underscores.